# Very short submissions in mathematics

Tags: publications

Regarding publishing a paper on mathematics, are very short notes, say a page or two or even half a page, publishable in mathematics?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, see for example [this question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3099/what-is-the-shortest-paper-in-the-history-of-mathematics) over at History of Science and Mathematics SE. This links to a few papers that are only a page long:

- [Eigenvalues of the Laplace operator on certain manifolds](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC300113/?page=1)
- [Counterexample to Euler's Conjecture](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1966-72-06/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3.pdf)
- [Can n² + 1 unit equilateral triangles cover an equilateral triangle of side > n, say n + ε?](http://fermatslibrary.com/s/shortest-paper-ever-published-in-a-serious-math-journal-john-conway-alexander-soifer)

Comment: The first two are old (> 50 years). The last one hasn't been published in a peer-reviewed journal, as far as I know.

Comment: @N.I. see the January 2005 issue of the American Mathematical Monthly.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche [What am I supposed to see?](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly/american-mathematical-monthly-january-2005) In any case, I cannot find the article either in mathscinet or zbmath. Also, that journal isn't a research journal.

Comment: @N.I. The American Mathematical Monthly is well refereed for correctness (among other things) and a good place to publish new research that's (sometimes surprisingly) accessible to the ordinary professional mathematician. What is your personal definition of "research journal"?

Comment: @N.I. I see your point.  The "paper" is on page 78 of the AMM Jan. 2005 issue, but is considered a "filler" and so is not listed in the table of contents.

Comment: @N.I. "*Also, that journal isn't a research journal.*"  The OP's question doesn't specify a "research journal."

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Thanks for the clarification. No, the OP's question doesn't specify "research journal", you're right.

Comment: @EthanBolker Do you want an honest answer? A journal in which, if you publish an article, you can list in your CV under the section "Publications" and expect it will make a difference when comparing your *research* output to other applicants. It's a subjective definition. What is your definition of research journal?

Comment: I am certainly not trying to denigrate the AMM. And the publication has value, for sure. Publishing in it has value for yourself, your career progression, and for the readership. But I think we can all agree that a journal which states "Novelty and generality are far less important than clarity of exposition and broad appeal." is not of the same kind as what is traditionally called "peer-reviewed academic journal". It's peer-reviewed, academic, and a journal, but the expression has a certain connotation that is not applicable here.

Answer (score 2):

Two and three page papers are rather common.  The Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society used to have a section called "Shorter Notes" that had a page limit of three.  This has been ended, but it is easy to find a two-pages paper published there in the past year or so, and many three-page papers.

It seems that two-page papers are often published.  At one page and below it is possible but rare enough to be noteworthy.

Back when PAMS had a shorter notes section, it ran this description [see the "about journal" bit](https://www.jstor.org/stable/i335942).  "A section called Shorter Notes was established to publish very short papers of unusually elegant and polished character for which there is normally no other outlet."

So at one time it was seen as difficult to publish shorter notes.  Perhaps it is easier now that the competition for our attention is the twitter and not a newspaper.